# How to solve this knapsack with dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given `N` objects and they are `1~n`, the volume of the i-th object is `ti` and `ti <= M`; Meanwhile, there are many boxes, and the volume of each box is `M`. Now we should put all these objects into boxes with **the order of 1~N**, what the minimum number of boxes should be used?

For example, there are 5 objects and their volume are `{7,2,5,3,9}` with order 1~5. The volume of each box is 10. So the optimal solution is 3 boxes and they are `{7}，{2，5，3}，{9}` respectively.

My solution: **greedy algorithm**. Suppose the optimal solution of the i-th object is x boxes are filled and the remaining space is y,then for the i+1 object, if its volume is larger than y, it has to be put into another new box. Otherwise, one option is that put it into the current box, and the solution is (x, y-v); the other option is that put it into another new box, and solution is (x+1, M-v).

**Question**: How to solve it with dynamic programming?

Comment: Try to google for bin packing problem.

Comment: here is one good example for my question, [http://amininima.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/dynamic-programming/](http://amininima.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/dynamic-programming/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why would you want to solve it using DP, since you have a perfectly good greedy solution, but here is the DP-based idea:

Let `F(k)` be the answer for first `k` objects - minimum number of boxes we can put them into.
Let's loop through how many objects do we put in the last box:

```
F(k) = min{F(l) + 1|l < k, t_(l+1) + t_(l+2) + .. + t_(k) <= M}
F(0) = 0
```

Complexity is `O(N*N)` if we compute sums of `t_i` on the fly for each `k`